# strcmp - поведение в виндоус, линукс и valgrind

Tags: linux, c, windows, строки, valgrind

Обнаружил очень не забавную вещь при программировании: функция `strcmp` возвращает разные значения при одних и тех же условиях на разных системах и даже при запуске в одной и той же системе через `valgrind`! Короче, создал прогу, которая в зависимости от значения `strcmp` через `switch` определяет какая команда ей была дадена. Тобишь если `0` - это `put`, если `9` - это `get` и т.д. Но, если запускаю прогу через `valgrind` или на винде, то функция возвращает только символы `-1 0 1`. Почему так?

Comment: `strcmp()` возвращает одно из трёх: положительное значение, отрицательное значение, ноль... Код в студию, или вопрос не понятен...

Comment: Потому что по стандарту она возвращает или ноль, или больше нуля, или меньше нуля. А что именно больше/меньше нуля — кто как хочет, тот так и делает. Во всех учебниках по си написано же не привязываться к конкретным возвращаемым значениям

Comment: ну так ладно на разных системах - но почему при запуске через `valgrind` работает по другому?

Comment: наверное valgrind перехватывает вызов для проверки границ операндов или ещё-какую-нить чёрную магию делает... это не то, о чём надо волноваться... `strcmp ()` может поменять своё поведение в рамках оговоренных правил хоть в зависимости от погоды на Марсе...

Comment: Да уж, досадно... теперь вместо `switch` придется громоздить `else if`

Comment: Нет кода - нет вопроса.

Comment: Тоесть, по-твоему без кода вопрос не понятен? Какой код ты вообще хочешь? Вопрос по конкретной ф-ции из стандартной библиотеки!

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: Вторая часть вопроса без кода совершенно не понятна. "...в зависимости от значения `strcmp` через `switch` определяет какая команда ей была дадена. Тобишь если `0` - это `put`, если `9` - это `get` и т.д..." - вот это какая-то непереводимая феерическая игра слов. Какое еще `9`??? Нужен код.

Comment: разница между `p` и `g` == 9 - на линуксе `strcmp` выдает разницу между этими буквами, а на винде просто показывает какая из этих букв больше. Так понятно?

Comment: Почему не сделать просто `switch(с){case 'p':{... break;} case 'g':{... break;} }` если вы все равно только по одной букве проверяете?

Comment: А кто сказал, что проверка по одной букве? strcmp сравнивает строки.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: Нет, по прежнему не понятно. Как это у вас используется в `switch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открываем стандарт:

> **7.24.4.2 The strcmp function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `strcmp` function compares the string pointed to by `s1` to the
>   string pointed to by `s2`.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `strcmp` function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or
>   less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by `s1` is
>   greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by `s2`.
>
> *ISO/IEC 9899:201x Committee Draft — April 12, 2011 N1570*

Примерный перевод:

> **7.24.4.2 Функция strcmp**
>
> **Синопсис**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> **Описание**
>
> Функция `strcmp` сравнивает строку, указываемую `s1`, со строкой, указываемую `s2`.
>
> **Возвращаемое значение**
>
> Функция `strcmp` возвращает целое число большее, равное, или меньшее нуля,  если строка `s1` больше, равна, или меньше строки `s2` соответственно.

Стандарт не говорит, какое **конкретно** число возвращать. Главное, что оно должно быть больше, меньше или равно нулю (в соответствующих случаях). Т.е. разработчик может реализовать ее каким угодно способом. Если `s1 > s2` можно вернуть `1`, можно `2`, а можно `255` и такая реализация будет соответствовать стандарту.

---

Вот так `strcmp` [реализована](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/string/strcmp.c) в FreeBSD:

```
int
strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 == *s2++)
        if (*s1++ == '\0')
            return (0);
    return (*(const unsigned char *)s1 - *(const unsigned char *)(s2 - 1));
}
```

---

Вот [так](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c) в Apple:

```
int
strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    for ( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++)
    if (*s1 == '\0')
        return 0;
    return ((*(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2) ? -1 : +1);
}
```

**UPD**

До меня таки начал доходить "истинный" смысл вопроса.

> Разница между `p` и `g` == 9 - на линуксе `strcmp` выдает разницу между
>   этими буквами, а на винде просто показывает какая из этих букв больше.
>   Так понятно? – Andrej Levkovitch

Как видно, код FreeBSD возвращает разницу между символами, а код Apple (как, видимо, и Microsoft) — ±1.

Comment: Обратите внимание, стандарт (как это частенько бывает) не до конца описывает, что значит меньше-больше. В функцию передаются **`char *`**, а вот в реализациях возвращается результат сравнения 2-х **`unsigned char`**

Comment: @avp, на самом деле этот момент также оговорен в стандарте. Пункт 7.24.1/3 относительно всех функций из заголовочного файла `<string.h>` говорит следующее: "For all functions in this subclause, each _character_ shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value)".